# Mechanism for linux output in terminal when using system function read() & write()

Tags: c, unix, terminal, stdout

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int n;

    while((n = read(0, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0 && printf("1:%d ", n))
    {
        printf("2:%d ", n);
        write(1, buf, n);
    }

    return 0;
}

pupu(my input)
pupu(output)
popopo(my input)
popopo(output)
1:5 2:5 1:7 2:7(output)
```

My question: How does it work?

(why buffer text output before n_read?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard I/O functions (like `printf`) are *buffered*, meaning output to `stdout` isn't printed until its buffer is full or explicitly flushed.

On the other hand, writing directly to the output file descriptor is *not* buffered and is written directly.

What you have here is you mixing direct and buffered output, and the buffered output isn't actually written until the program exits and the buffer is flushed.

Comment: Thank you, should i learn its source code? I just learn the usage of some easy system functions.